# How do i filter API responses in nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make a chat app using the following Components (i just write everything here, because I don't know which information are important, sorry):
Angular, Nodejs, Expressjs, MongoDB, Mongoose

I have multiple DB entries for `localhost:3000/message` in the schema of `[{content: "this is a message(text)", sender: "1337(number)", receiver:"42(number)"}]`

Now i want to display in my angular page only the entries where the current user (via his by mongo generated ID) is either a sender of receiver (so basically the messages he is alowed to see).

Of course i canrequest all messages and then filter them in my frontend, but this seems to me like bad practice and a massive security issue if i want to put the page online and everyone can request all the messages if they find the api.

A different approach I thought of is making a route to `/message/:userID` where his messages are stored. This may conflict with `/message/:messageID` where you can put/delete a single massage. This is not very likely but very problematic if it occurs

What shall I choose and how to do it or is there a mighty tool/practice that i didn't find yet?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely let mongoose do a query to only get the documents you need - it's easier and more secure to let the server do this rather then do the sorting/filtering in the frontend. I assume you know about the mongoose queries and only focusing on your endpoint problem.

## Use clear API Endpoints

When I work with Express and API Endpoints I try to make them as clear as possible. In your example I would implement the following routes. In this case I assume you are using JWT Tokens to authenticate the user.

### Non user-specific messages

- **Get a specific message from the message pool**
  `app.get('/messages/:id')`
- **Get all messages from the message pool**
  `app.get('/messages')`

### User-specific messages

- **Get a specific message from user**
  `app.get('/user/messages/:id')`
- **Get all messages from user**
  `app.get('/user/messages')`

---

Other then that, if you use various available HTTP Request Types, like `PUT` and `DELETE` you can get even more diversion.

### Update/Delete user-specific messages

- **Delete specific message from user**
  `app.delete('/user/messages/:id')`
- **Update specific message from user**
  `app.put('/user/messages/:id')`

---

I kind of depends on how you authenticate the user, and how the user object/information will be available in the request. Include the user id in the request body ? Use `passport` and JWT Token to retrieve the user object in a middleware ? Many possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, this works, to add: I did /user/:userId/message, this seemed more intuitive to me

Comment: Totally fine and legit approach to include the userid in the request url.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options.

- Change the path of one so it is unique.
- Combine them into one route handler and devise how to tell which piece of logic
  you want to execute from other conditions.

```
GET /message/:id?action=<the_action_you_have_to_do ex: delete/get_messages>
```

```js
app.get('/message/:id', (req, res) => {
    req.query.action === 'delete'
    // perform delete functions
    req.query.action === 'get_messages'
    // retrive messages
})
```

- Use a more involved route definition so that each route definition you actually tell
  the difference between the two routes.

```js
app.get('user/message/:id', (req, res) => {
    // perform delete functions
})
```

```js
app.get('/message/:id', (req, res) => {
    // retrive messages
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I started out with your approach of the routing. Pascals answer is more precise, so I'll mark it as correct, if I could, I would mark both correct